# How to input a value to a cell based on a range of other cells

Tags: excel

**To: Stack Overflow**

I have read the solution provided to this *stackoverflow.com/questions/41416948/ms-excel-copy-contents-of-clicked-active-cell-to-another-cell.*

My query is similar but it involves more than 2 separate groups of clicked choices in the same worksheet.

For example, in my worksheet ("FillData"), a value will be input to **Cell E7** based on the range **E10:E101**, the other value will be input to **Cell S7** based on **S10:S101** respectively.

I have tried to modify the code by trial and error- the code actually works but i feel that what i have modified is not elegant because there are some repetitions of instruction such as below:-

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
If Selection.Count = 1 Then
 'Put in your actual range and the cell where you the text to be shown
    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("E10:E101")) Is Nothing Then
        Range("E7").Value = Selection.Value
        End If
End If

If Selection.Count = 1 Then
 'Put in your actual range and the cell where you the text to be shown
    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("S10:S101")) Is Nothing Then
        Range("S7").Value = Selection.Value
End If
End If
```

I would appreciate it if you could advise how this code could be refined. Thank you.

**From LC Tan 10 August 2019**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know, questions regarding refinement are more appropriate for Code Review Stack Exchange. Also, the code in your question appears to be missing an `End Sub` line. Presume this is just due to a bad paste.

In my opinion, since the code is quite short, there isn't too much to say other than:

- It doesn't make sense to perform the `Selection.Count` twice. So maybe just do it once and move the second `If Not Intersect...` block.
- If you invert the `Selection.Count` check, you can exit early and reduce the indentation levels in the rest of the procedure.
- Maybe use `Target` instead of `Selection`.
- Maybe use `Me.Range` instead of just `Range` (although this might be unnecessary).
- Maybe `Range.CountLarge` is a better property to use during the check (even if the possibility of overflow error/selecting ~2.1 billion cells is unlikely).
- Maybe disable events at the start and end of the routine to prevent infinite loop/recursion due to other events firing. (If you do this, maybe have a `On Error GoTo ...` statement to ensure `Application.EnableEvents` is restored even if an error occurs.)

Overall, your code might then look like:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Target.Cells.CountLarge <> 1 Then Exit Sub

    If Not Intersect(Target, Me.Range("E10:E101")) Is Nothing Then
        Me.Range("E7").Value = Target.Value
    End If

    If Not Intersect(Target, Me.Range("S10:S101")) Is Nothing Then
        Me.Range("S7").Value = Target.Value
    End If
End Sub
```

If the repeated `If Not Intersect...` statements bother you, you could either replace them with a function or a loop. Or you could use the below (if you find it to be readable).

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Target.Cells.CountLarge <> 1 Then Exit Sub
    If Target.Row < 10 Or Target.Row > 101 Then Exit Sub
    If Intersect(Me.Range("E:E,S:S"), Target) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub

    Me.Cells(7, Target.Column).Value = Target.Value
End Sub
```

There are many ways to express the same logic.

Answer (score 0):

**To: Chilin**

Thank you very much for your help on the above with 2 solutions that are effective.  They are not only elegant, they work after I tried out both solutions. Thank you very much.

**From LC Tan 14 August 2019**